# Update to sql server table is giving error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/TDSWriter$1

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc

The update to SQL Server table works fine when I run my application locally. But it gives me the error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/TDSWriter$1" when I try to run the deployed version on jenkins on our linux server.

I am using org.springframework.data.repository.save for updating my record in the table.

```
try{
    userRepository.save(personnel);
}catch (Exception e){
    String message = "There is an exception while updating userrecord in the database";
logger.error(message, e);
}
```

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/TDSWriter$1
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter.writeRPCByteArray(IOBuffer.java:4526)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV$SendByRPCOp.execute(dtv.java:1158)com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.executeOp(dtv.java:1311)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DTV.sendByRPC(dtv.java:1503)

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved. On the linux server where the application was deployed I there were multiple versions of the sqljdbc jar. Only one sql jdbc jar(sqljdbc42.jar) is required. So removing the other sql jdbc jar has solved this issue. It worked in my local since I dont have multiple version on my system.